# Creating CLR Assembly in SQLServer 2005

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I am getting the following error message when I try install my .NET assembly int SqlServer 2005. 
My .NET assembly references 'ChilkatDotNet2.dll' assembly.

```
Msg 6544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'myassembly' failed because assembly 'chilkatdotnet2' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.
```

Any ideas how to resolve, workaround?

Comment: This seems more like a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the ChilkatDotNet2.dll assembly is using an unsupported assembly (for example, you can't reference any of the SMO libraries in the SQLCLR) or some other restriction violation. Check your ChilkatDotNet2.dll against the restriction list [here][1] and the link to supported assemblies embedded within that link (can't add 2 hyperlinks)

HTH,

Chad